# How can I create this type of design using HTML 5 canvas?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hello everyone can anyone help me with how I can create this kind of design I'm trying to make this using Html 5 canvas, but my rectangles are overlapping each other and do not fit in the canvas. I'm attaching the reference design and screenshot of my design.

[This is the reference design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpLvT.jpg)

[This is what I made so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Adg.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./home.css";

const Home = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const contextRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 1000;

    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    contextRef.current = context;
    drawRect();
  }, []);

  function drawRect() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      // contextRef.current.style.width = 5;
      contextRef.current.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
      contextRef.current.fillRect(
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        6,
        15
      );
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      contextRef.current.fillStyle = "#fff";
      contextRef.current.fillRect(
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        12,
        30
      );
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
      contextRef.current.fillStyle = "#fece2f";
      contextRef.current.fillRect(
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        24,
        45
      );
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      contextRef.current.fillStyle = "#FFB6C1";
      contextRef.current.fillRect(
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        36,
        60
      );
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      contextRef.current.fillStyle = "#ff80ed";
      contextRef.current.fillRect(
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
        40,
        75
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <main className="main-content">
      *<canvas ref={canvasRef} className="canvas-container"></canvas>
    </main>
  );
};
```

export default Home;

and the CSS

```
.main-content {
  height: 78vh;
  margin: 25px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

.canvas-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping problem can be solved specifying appropriate z-index in CSS rules.

You can see some simple similar examples in [responsive-web-design](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/2022/responsive-web-design) which may help. (particularly city skyline and picas painting steps)